# socket.io "Cross-Origin request Blocked" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So, I'm trying to follow along [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppcBIHv_ZPs) tutorial and right off the bat I can't get it to work.
First off, these are my files:

**root/frontend/index.html**

```
<html>
  [...]some static page[...]

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

**root/frontend/index.js**

```
const socket=io('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('init', handleInit);

function handleInit(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
}
```

**root/server/server.js**

```
const io=require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', client =>{
  client.emit('init', {data:'hello'});
});

io.listen(3000);
```

What he does next is running "npx live-server" in the frontend folder (which I also do). And also, run "yarn add socket.io" in the server folder and then run "npx nodemon server.js" and it's supposed to work. But doing those exact steps I get the errors:
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NsGvIgN. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)"

and

"GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NsGvO1Z"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I kinda figured it out.

In the end I end up following another tutorial which is much simpler and much better for the starter. It's [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Br4uaXHrODg). Easy to understand, to the point, compact and works with no issues.

But if you encounter this CORS error then the way to fix it is in [another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU-HfZY3ATQ) video. Basically you have to install the cors package and add some definitions in the server js code. The fix itself is in the 10 minute mark, but I suggest watching from the start.